# Should a Nightly build be incremental?

Tags: tfs, build, incremental-build

We have a nightly build that currently cleans the entire workspace and builds all projects from the ground up and then runs integration tests on them. But this process takes quite a while - around 10 hours.

Using an incremental build could save at least half an hour, but would that be a good practice for a nightly build that just runs tests and the output of the nightly is not used anywhere?

Comment: What's the breakdown of your 10 hour build time? How much time is spent getting sources, building, running tests, etc. What type of code are you building (native, managed, something else)? There are a number of techniques that could be applied, but they vary depending on your technology stack. Of course, you can also throw hardware at the problem (faster CPU, faster storage, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not a good practice. The best practice is to trigger a Nightly build with the packaged solution from a Release build.

Comment: Yes, your nightly build should be a full rebuild of a release (non-Debug) configuration. You should also generate debugging symbols from that build so that you have them available.